# SQL Server database back-up operation takes long time

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I try to take back-up of an SQL server database (around 1000 GB) the time taken for the process varies each time.

Sometimes the back-up process completes within 70 mins and some times takes around 3 hours or so.

What could be the reason for the variation in backup times?

Can someone tell me the factors which influence the back-up time in SQL Server and the steps that could be taken to reduce the backup time?

Here are the details of the server box from which the backup is initiated:

1. MS Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
2. Processor with 2.60 Ghz frequency
3. RAM - More than 300 gb

Additional info: All drives are SSD and back-up is taken with compression.

The back-up target is a remote network location carried out over a 1 GBPS bandwidth network.

Comment: looks more like a question for https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you already considered storing the backup locally and move it to the network storage location in a second step to take network transfer out of the equation?

Comment: @Filburt yes but there are storage constraints and i first wanted to know the root cause of this issue

Comment: It might well be that network reliability is the cause, so if you can (temporarily) have the local storage you should try.

Answer (score 0):

So 1000 GB is the total size of DB datafiles, what about  transaction log files ?

Are transaction log(s) included in your backup ?
A Database can be using a simple recovery mode, so basically nothing is written on the log files, or can be working with logfiles which are keeping db changes not committed. 
Once they got committed the transaction log generally stay there (and grow) until a full backup with the flag to truncate log is completed.
According to the workload the size of transaction log files can vary a lot from one backup to another one despite the Database size changed slightly so the total data to be backup up can vary a lot too, and obviously the time to complete the full backup process.

In my experience the backup when there have been almost no user activity, i.e. on Sunday evening, are a lot faster of the ones after a certain number of transaction due to the increased size of logfile.

Comment: At one time, a full back up was performed ant it took 67 mins,  the next day when the same db was backed up it took around 113 min. Hiw should i explain this?  That's why i was interested in the factors that affect the back up time.